# Merge wifi-hotspot and wifi-tethering?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Obviously both are the very same thing. I'd suggest to merge them and converting the remaining one (depending on which is the merging target) into a synonym.

Comment: This came up a while back (in 2010, it looks like): [wifi tags - are wifi-tethering and wifi-hotspot redundant?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/132) It might be worth revisiting, though.

Comment: Agreed. And as to Matt's answer there: one could still use two tags (e.g. wifi-hotspot and tether) if really necessary. Though I'd say most people don't distinguish the two. Is there really a technical difference between the two terms wifi-tethering and wifi-hotspot? I'm not aware of any (except you'd count an ad-hoc connection not as a hotspot, which might be an argument -- but still could be pointed to by using two tags then: wifi-hotspot and ad-hoc-networks)

Comment: I guess tethering over an ad-hoc connection may, from a technical standpoint, be different than a hotspot, as it wouldn't really be an AP in that situation. It would be essentially behaving like one, but I suppose it wouldn't *really* be one. I'm not sure if that alone is a convincing enough reason to leave them separated or not, though.

Comment: Exactly my point: only hair-splitting makes a difference here. And those who insist on *that* difference are rather discussing it at other SO "branches" (oh, there isn't a Networking SO? I thought there was...). So 1:0 pro merging the two :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that these are actually different things:

[wifi-hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-hotspot)could represent any wifi network, or a public 'wifi hotspot'.

[wifi-tethering](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-tethering) would mainly represent the actual process of tethering, or creating a hotspot.

As such, I don't think they should be merged.

Comment: As said: when concerned about the *process*, one could use `wifi-hotspot` and `tether` to indicate this. Too many "similar" tags are IMHO not that helpful -- it gets harder to utilize them for searching, as you first need to figure out which are available. But OK, that's *my* opinion...